# How to set the SSL options when connecting to Heroku in Phoenix framework?

Tags: ssl, heroku, phoenix-framework, ecto

I recently upgraded Phoenix to the newest version(1.7.7) and Ecto was also upgraded to 3.10.3. Before upgrading, when connecting to Heroku pg, i just set `SSL: true` and the connection is OK:

```
config :abc, abc.Repo,
  url: System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"),
  pool_size: String.to_integer(System.get_env("POOL_SIZE") || "10"),
  ssl: true
```

After upgrading, it failed with the following messages:

```
[error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.2449.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) ssl connect: Options (or their values) can not be combined: [{verify,verify_peer},
                                                {cacerts,undefined}] - {:options, :incompatible, [verify: :verify_peer, cacerts: :undefined]}
```

It seemed more options were needed now. There are a lot options and i can't find some examples about how to set them. By the way, Heroku pg mandated the SSL option set, so i can't remove it. Anyone one runs into same problem?

Comment: Same problem with my install. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here:

https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-set-ssl-options-correctly-when-connecting-to-heroku-postgres-db/59426/2

```
config :abc, abc.Repo,
  [...]
  ssl_opts: [verify: :verify_none]
```

Comment: The [link](https://www.erlang.org/blog/otp-26-highlights/#ssl-safer-defaults) you were provided suggests adding`cacerts :public_key.cacerts_get()`. Have you tried it?

Comment: The docs indicates that `server_name_indication: String.to_charlist(host_name)` might be needed as well